# Sudden pop when turning, what could be cause?

Tags: noise, knock

I have an old civic em1 1999.

The car has recently been making a knocking noise from underneath and infront of the clutch area it seems.  Showed it to a mechanic he said it was most likely anti roll bar or ball joints.

Today I was accelerating and did a sudden right turn and heard a loud pop sound as though you just ran over a plastic bottle on the street.  of course I didnt see anything on the street.  I didnt see this sound repeat today.

What might be the cause of such a sound?  Might it be related to the anti roll bar or ball joint issues?

btw if I do have problems with my roll bar or ball joints is it still safe for me to drive in the meantime?

Thanks

Comment: You can drive a car without a roll bar (or sway bar or anti-sway bar ... whatever you'd like to call it). The pop could have been the sway bar unloading, but I doubt it. It will just drive a little bit *squishy* in the corners. If it is your ball joint, this is a huge safety item as if the ball joint should go, your lose control of the vehicle because one of your tires will fold out and you'll no longer have control of it. The action will cause the other side to pull over as well as most likely pull the steering wheel out of your hand.

Comment: There's *something* wrong with your car; either rollbar, CV Joint or Ball Joint. You don't really want any of those to fail. Drive it (carefully) to a couple of shops and get some quotes. I wouldn't want to drive it too far in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

it's usually the ball joint on the opposite side of the direction you turn in.  If they go bad, they can freeze and you can get a pop as it unseizes.  It could also be a cv axle but you would have probably felt that.  They have a tendency to rock the car.  Depending on the "Pop" (vague description really) it could in fact be a sway bar if the bushing is out of it, although I would expect the bang to be on the left as it slams into the frame.